# drop column from dataframe if all values in this column are a specific value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Data-Sample:

```
choice   col1  col2  col3
1    100   110   100
2    110   110   100
5    110   110   100
...
50   100   200   300
```

should become:

```
choice   col1  col2
1    100   110
2    110   110
5    110   110
...
50   100   200
```

trying to delete column 3 if all values **except row 50** of the column are 100.

tried to use:

```
df['col3'].all() == 100
or
df['col3'].any() == 100
```

both lines neither give a result nor create an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`df.all()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) to return `True/False` whether condition meets from [`df.eq()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and invert `True` to `False` and vice versa with invert `~` , finally filter `True` columns with the help of [`df.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[:,~df.eq(100).all()]
```

---

```
  id  col1  col2
   1   100   110
   2   110   110
   3   110   110
```

EDIT: per edit, you can try a custom function with simiilar logic:

```
def myfunc(x,choice):
    x=x.set_index('choice')
    cond=x.loc[:,'col3'].drop(choice).eq(100).all()
    if cond:
        return x.drop('col3',1).reset_index()
    else:
        return x.reset_index()
myfunc(df,'50') #if choice column is an integer myfunc(df,50)
```

---

```
  choice   col1   col2
0      1  100.0  110.0
1      2  110.0  110.0
2      5  110.0  110.0
3     50  100.0  200.0
```

Comment: what if i have 1 row lets say 50 where some reference values are stored like 100, 200, 300. any way i can exclude them from the 100 comparison?

Comment: @J.Doe i ddnt understand, can you edit the question with more details and expected output, i will have more clarity then

Comment: edited the question. check if every row of col3 is 100 except row 50 and if so delete col3 completly

Comment: @J.Doe ok, so we just check for col3(not all columns?)? also we check if col3 values except index 50 is 100? if both satisfies drop col3? am i correct?

Comment: correct, check col3 for 100 in all rows except 50. it is not index but a col where the col value would be 50. the col choice which for simplicity is not listed in the example above. so it is not always at position 50 it can also be the 40th of the list because not every choice has to be activated. adapted that to the original question too

Comment: @J.Doe can you test with the new function now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198866/discussion-between-j-doe-and-anky-91).

Answer (score 1):

Also you can do:

```
df=df.T[~df.eq(100).all()].T
```

Output:

```
  id  col1  col2
   1   100   110
   2   110   110
   3   110   110
```

Comment: Transpose dataframe